# Gutenberg select categories

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I have the following code

```
wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'category' );
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEntityRecords' of null
at Module../src/index.js (index.js:6)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at bootstrap:152
at bootstrap:152
```

If i install another plugin that has nothing to do with this plugin my code works. So i tought that i might forget someting to include.